# How to add a custom common input field for all of the widgets in the wordpress admin sidebars

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, sidebar, custom-fields

I am trying to add a common input field for all of the widgets in the Wordpress admin sidebars. Although I was able to show an input field, but how can I save data for each of the active widgets separately with their own values?

This is how I started:

```
add_action('in_widget_form', 'add_common_widget_fields');
function add_common_widget_fields($widget){
    echo '<p><label>Custom Widget Data:</label> <input type="text" name="customdata" value="My_Value" /></p>';
}
```